# Error in adding crashlytics in my ios app (xcode 6.1.1)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I am facing issue in adding crashlytics in my app.Downloaded latest fabric app for mac and followed steps at final step to run project faced this issue

[image: Error]

Comment: try to clean by pressing Command+Shift+K and re build it

Comment: tried this not working

Comment: Okay first of all you should update your Xcode atleast to 7.3. Secondly no need to download the fabric app on mac. just follow these instructions and you will be good to go https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install